# How to burn Tokens in a Solana wallet

Tags: spl-token, wallet, address

I want to burn tokens like in Ethereum where you send them in a dead address, and I was wondering if it's safe to send tokens to this wallet: dead111111111111111111111111111111111111111
I'm still a noob in solana unfortunately. I know that usually the burn is made via direct burn, reducing the supply. But I want the supply to remain intact.
I saw that some NFT's are sent to a wallet made of just 1's. So would anyone be able to interact with this dead111111111111111111111111111111111111111 wallet and take the tokens?
Thank you in advance for the time spent reading this.

Answer (score 2):

The typical "dead" address in Solana is the incinerator address of `1nc1nerator11111111111111111111111111111111`, so some people will create an account held by this account and send tokens to it. I believe they can still be burned by anyone in that case though.

If you want the tokens to stick around, the other convention is to create a token account held by the system program of `11111111111111111111111111111111` and send the tokens there.

Comment: got it, thank you very much man!

Answer (score 1):

On Solana it doesn't work this way, instead there's an operation to burn the tokens. Most wallets have an option to do this from the UI.

In the attached screenshot you see Solflare wallet showing the context menu with the Burn & Close option.

[image: Screenshot of Solflare wallet showing the context menu with the Burn & Close option]

If you run this, the wallet will prompt you to sign the transaction with a warning, and if you proceed, the tokens and the 'token account' will be gone.

[image: Solflare Wallet Prompt to sign a transaction that burns tokens]

Another way to do it is by using an app like [Sol Incinerator](https://sol-incinerator.com/) built for burning tokens!

If you are working on an app and want to integrate it, look at [this example](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/spl-tokens/how-to-burn-spl-tokens-on-solana).

Comment: Got it, thank you very much for the answer. I might use the incinerator in the future! Also the Solflare wallet seems super handy.
Anyway this time I would like to use the burn in the way I mentioned, for a visual reason. I know doesn't change anything, but I just wanted to have a visually reduced supply %. If I burn the tokens the % of supply will increase and I wanted it to be low. I'm going to burn the tokens before launch not after.
Solana provides this good tool of burning, but in this case I prefer the dead address one. Is there any address that is safe sending tokens to?

Comment: If you want the token supply to go down, the only thing that does that is by using the `burn` instruction. That's the only way to make the 'circulating supply' counter on the explorers go down. Sending it to an address you don't own removes it from your wallet, but doesn't change anything about the supply. Maybe the burn option on Step helps, it lets you burn a specific amount of tokens - not directly all of them. https://app.step.finance/en/dashboard